# How to save user input in onCreate method

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this program that counts how many points each team has.

All what I want is that updating the score when one or two teams enter there new scores, basically a program to keep track of teams scores.

```
public class LanaLuhm extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lana_luhm);

    final EditText firstTeam= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFirstTeam);
    final EditText eFirstTeam= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textFirstTeam);


    final EditText secondTeam= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inpuSecondTeam);
    final EditText eSecondTeam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSecondTeam);


    final Button count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCount);
    count.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
            int getFirstTeam = Integer.valueOf(firstTeam.getText().toString());
            int getSecondTeam = Integer.valueOf(secondTeam.getText().toString());

            eFirstTeam.setText(String.valueOf(getFirstTeam ));
            eSecondTeam .setText(String.valueOf(getSecondTeam ));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.print("you can't do that!"); 
            }

        }
    });



}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lana_luhm, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you tried saving the information in sharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to save team scores.

```
//To save team score
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();

e.putString("teamScore1", firstTeam.getText().toString()); //1st Team
e.putString("teamScore2", secondTeam.getText().toString()); //2nd Team

e.commit();

//Retrieve team score
String team1 = settings.getString("teamScore1", "");
String team2 = settings.getString("teamScore2", "");
```